Instantiate custom Lexer and Parser in memory with ANTLR4 in Python
I want to implement a generic parsing capability, the inputs are grammar files and it would return a lexer and parser, in Python.
The common use-case code takes the grammar files and generates python classes which represent the custom Lexer and Parser, those are used to generate the AST.
I want to skip the py file generation.
It looks like the custom files only add constants but wasn't able to find a builder for the Lexer and Parser.

"I want to skip the py file generation.", alas, there is no Python builder for ANTLR grammars. So to create source files for the lexer and parser, you'd have to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-do-i-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command
